# CNN can't predict images outside the dataset

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision

I am using celeba dataset to train my CNN face landmark detection model.
Here is my model

```
class LandmarkModel:
    def __init__(self,inp_shape):
        self.model = models.Sequential()
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=inp_shape))#l1
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(3, 3), activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        self.model.add(layers.Conv2D(64,(3, 3), activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(layers.Flatten())
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(512))
        self.model.add(layers.Dense(10))

    def getModel(self):
        return self.model
```

I have trained my model for around 5k-6k images with loss of 0.1.
When I use image from dataset that is outside of training sample I get correct prediction.
But when I use my own clicked images predictions are completely off. I have clicked photos exactly like in dataset.
I have also tried with downloaded celeb images still wrong predictions.
What is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Are you preprocessing any new images in the same way as your training and validation images?

Comment: @Oxbowerce Yes. As I said Validation Images from dataset works but not for my images

Comment: A little bit offtop, but why `Dense(512)` doesn't have activation?

Comment: @LOLs perhaps some printouts from training and evaluation phases would help verify the process.

Answer (score 0):

That could a lot of reasons for that. For example, images are sometimes represented with numbers in range 0-1 and sometimes in range 0-255 and it's very easy to mix these ranges for in-dataset / external as the model would fail silently without any warnings.

In general, if the same model gives you different results, then images are not exactly the same.
I suggest you take the same image from your dataset and internet and compare the raw numbers on the input of the model. If results different, then input tensors should be different and you can check your preprocessing pipeline step by step to find the point of discrepancy.

The debugging tools like [ipdb](https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/) are usually very useful in such situations.

Comment: Can you tell any other reasons. Both the image value are similar and image format is also same

Comment: I didn't mean similar, I mean exact. Take the image from dataset, make reverse search by image with something like https://images.google.com/, find the _exact_ same photo in the internet, apply the approach I proposed.

Comment: It's a lot of small thing to mess up with neural net and unfortunately nobody can guess your problem without debugging your code. See, 1. What is the clicked images exactly? 2. Why don't you apply activation function on Dense(512)? 3. Double check you didn't use validation samples during training 4. It's good idea to split by identities, i.e. use all photo of a specific person either in train or val 5. Make sure you don't apply training augmentations during inference, etc, etc.

Comment: You can try a lot of things from this thread https://twitter.com/karpathy/status/1013244313327681536, but approach I proposed would be more direct and probably the fastest.

Comment: Can Image size cause problem? Cause my images are of different resolution than I have trained. I have resized to same but I still doubt that

Comment: @LOLs maybe. Plot the intensity histogram of of all 3 color channels of new images vs. training data right before feeding into model (after preprocessing). Do they show any significant difference?